# Using Span<T> as a replacement for Substring

Tags: c#, substring, system.memory

I have read a few articles about how Span can be used to replace certain string operations.  As such I have updated some code in my code base to use this new feature, however, to be able to use it in-place I then have to call `.ToString()`.

Does the `.ToString()` effectively negate the benefit I get from using `Span<T>` rather than `Substring` as this would have to allocate memory? In which case how do I reap the benefits if Span in this way, or is it just not possible?

```
//return geofenceNamesString.Substring(0, 50); Previous code
return geofenceNamesString.AsSpan().Slice(0, 50).ToString();
```

Comment: Yes; creating a `String` negates the benefit by allocating a string.  You need to return a `Span<T>`

Comment: My ultimate use of this is to store it in a database via EF, which is string type, I guess then I won't see the benefit for this particular use case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no benefit in your case.

A span is useful if you keep multiple "references" into the same array of data. For example if you read a file into RAM and then kept references to each line, so you don't have to *copy* each line, but only to keep its position in the big string.

You are making a copy of your string one way or another. So just go with the easier, more readable way of `Substring`.